# Explain the Lagrange error bound formula for me

Tags: taylor-expansion

The Lagrange error bound formula is represented as: $$R_n(x)\le \frac{M}{(n+1)!}|c-a|^{n+1}$$
Can anyone explain what each part of this formula means? I understand that $M$ represents a maximum value, and $a$ is where the series is centered. 
Specifically can someone explain the significance of $R_n(x)$, $(n+1)!$ in the denominator, and $|c-a|$ ? Also I know that changing $|c-a|$ changes the error bound, but could someone explain why that is the case?

Comment: I think a good source of intuition is to think about "what would the next term of the expansion be?" It would be $\frac{f^{(n+1)}(a)}{(n+1)!} (x-a)^{n+1}$. The Lagrange remainder formula (for the exact remainder, not a bound) is telling us that the *true* remainder is "almost" that, except that the $(n+1)$th derivative is evaluated at some unknown point $c$ between $x$ and $a$, not $a$ itself.

Comment: This discrepancy between $a$ and $c$ is pretty much the same discrepancy that you see in the mean value theorem (which is essentially Taylor's theorem with the Lagrange remainder specialized to $n=0$).